# How to create TimeZone relative to something else than UTC/GMT in java

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I need to create a timeZone which is a fix offset to America/New_York

I would like to do something like that (DateTime lib):
DateTimeZone MyTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York+17");

But it is not possible.

The only thing i can do - is to get current offset to UTC/GMT and shift it by my additional offset.

DateTimeZone.forOffsetMillis(NYTimeZone.getOffset(time)+dt)

But this is not efficient - because i need to know the current time to know the current offset.

Thanks

---

I have found ZoneTimeBuilder - here is an example on how it is used.

Do you know where to find the definition for New_York - this example is for LA..

DateTimeZone America_Los_Angeles = new DateTimeZoneBuilder()
     .addCutover(-2147483648, 'w', 1, 1, 0, false, 0)
     .setStandardOffset(-28378000)
     .setFixedSavings("LMT", 0)
     .addCutover(1883, 'w', 11, 18, 0, false, 43200000)
     .setStandardOffset(-28800000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PDT", 3600000, 1918, 1919, 'w',  3, -1, 7, false, 7200000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PST",       0, 1918, 1919, 'w', 10, -1, 7, false, 7200000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PWT", 3600000, 1942, 1942, 'w',  2,  9, 0, false, 7200000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PPT", 3600000, 1945, 1945, 'u',  8, 14, 0, false, 82800000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PST",       0, 1945, 1945, 'w',  9, 30, 0, false, 7200000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PDT", 3600000, 1948, 1948, 'w',  3, 14, 0, false, 7200000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PST",       0, 1949, 1949, 'w',  1,  1, 0, false, 7200000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PDT", 3600000, 1950, 1966, 'w',  4, -1, 7, false, 7200000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PST",       0, 1950, 1961, 'w',  9, -1, 7, false, 7200000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PST",       0, 1962, 1966, 'w', 10, -1, 7, false, 7200000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PST",       0, 1967, 2147483647, 'w', 10, -1, 7, false, 7200000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PDT", 3600000, 1967, 1973, 'w', 4, -1,  7, false, 7200000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PDT", 3600000, 1974, 1974, 'w', 1,  6,  0, false, 7200000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PDT", 3600000, 1975, 1975, 'w', 2, 23,  0, false, 7200000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PDT", 3600000, 1976, 1986, 'w', 4, -1,  7, false, 7200000)
     .addRecurringSavings("PDT", 3600000, 1987, 2147483647, 'w', 4, 1, 7, true, 7200000)
     .toDateTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles", true);

Comment: What version of Java? The answer to your question will largely depend on that...

Comment: But how inefficient is it really? Especially if you store the answer?

Comment: New York's offset will shift also (between UTC-5 and UTC-4) , so the net result would be a time zone that shifts between UTC+12 and UTC+13 at the same moments in time that the US Eastern time zone shifts.  Are you sure that's what you want?  Note that those transitions would occur at 5:00 PM local time in this new time zone.  That would be *quite* weird.

Comment: This is indeed a very odd requirement. Can you tell us more about what you're aiming to achieve? There may well be a better approach. Note that you *always* need to "know the current time to know the current offset" for anything other than fixed offset time zones... which the zone you're describing isn't.

Comment: 1/ To fge: using Java8 - 2/ to MattJohson: yes 5PM in NY will be the midnight of this new timezone.